# Homology of a graph - Weibel's Introduction to Homological Algebra exercise 1.1.6.

Tags: graph-theory, homological-algebra

The following is a question from Charles A. Weibel's *An Introduction to Homological Algebra:*

> **Exercise 1.1.6.** Let $\Gamma$ be a finite graph with $V$ vertices $(v_1, \ldots, v_V)$ and $E$ edges $(e_1, \ldots, e_E)$. If we orient the edges, we can form the *indcidence matrix* of the graph. This is a $V \times E$ matrix whose $(ij)$ entry is $+1$ if the edge $e_j$ starts at $v_i$, $-1$ if the edge  ends at $v_i$, and $0$ otherwise.
> Let $C_0$ be the free $R$-module on the vertices, $C_1$ the free $R$-module on the edges, $C_n=0$ if $n\ne 0,1$, and $d: C_1\rightarrow C_0$ be the incidence matrix.
>
> If $\Gamma$ is connected, show that $H_0(C)$ and $H_1(C)$ are free $R$-modules of dimensions $1$ and $V-E-1$ respectively.

I was able to do the first one and the last one seems to be incorrect. For example, [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343232/) asserts that the number must be $E - V + 1$.

The answer in the link solves it assuming that the module is free a priori and then compute the rank. The comment then says that one can solve it for $R = \Bbb Z$ and use something called as the Universal Coefficients Theorem. Since this is an earlier part in the book, I feel like there should be something simple. (I also don't know the Theorem, so I wish to see a different solution anyway.)

---

**My work.**

For $H_1$, the relevant part of the sequence is $$0 \to C_1 \xrightarrow{d} C_0.$$
Thus, we simply need to compute $\ker(d)$.

One can also note that $d$ is essentially acting as the "boundary map", i.e., given any edge $e$, we have $d(e) = v_i - v_j$, where $v_i$ is the starting point of $e$ and $v_j$ the ending point.

Thus, there are some obvious elements in the kernel: namely, all cycles. I have a hunch that the cycles will form a basis. At least, the number matches for some simple cases like the ones below.

[image]

However, it not clear to me why there would be $E + 1 - V$ many cycles.

Comment: Consider a spanning tree of the (un-oriented) graph. What can you say about each of the edges *not* in the spanning tree? Can you build cycles using them?

Comment: @Leo: $1$. Adding an edge from outside will introduce exactly one cycle. $2$. The spanning tree must have $V - 1$ edges, so there are $E - (V - 1)$ edges not in that tree (this gives me the number I wanted). $3$. However, I'm not quite sure if I can conclude that my original graph had $E - (V - 1)$ cycles to begin with. To elaborate: when I add one edge from outside, I get exactly one cycle. But now it is not a spanning tree anymore, so how do I guarantee that adding one more edge will introduce one extra cycle and not more?

Comment: The spanning tree is still a spanning tree after you add one edge. The spanning tree must contain all nodes, and that doesn't change if you add one edge.

Comment: @Leo: It won't remain a tree anymore, right?

Comment: Granting that you can prove your hunch, then we may proceed as follows. In any exact sequence of free $R$-modules $0\rightarrow ker(d) \rightarrow C_1 \rightarrow C_0 \rightarrow coker(d) \rightarrow 0$, we get that alternating sum of rank of the modules is zero. Using that rank of $coker(d), C_0$ and $C_1$ is respectively $1, |V|$ and $|E|$ respectively, we get the rank of $ker(d)$ to be $|E|-|V|+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete solution based on @Leo's hint. Choose a spanning tree, say it is the subgraph $T=\Gamma(e_1,...,e_{V-1})$ (since $\Gamma$ is connected, a spanning tree exists and has precisely $V-1$ edges.)

For an edge $e_i$ outside $T$, the graph $T\cup \{e_i\}$ has a unique cycle $c_i=e+\sum_{j=1}^{V-1}\mu_je_j$ where the coefficients $\mu_j\in \{\pm 1, 0\}$ are chosen to orient the edges appropriately so that $d(c_i)=0$. Then $\{e_1,...,e_{V-1}, c_V,...,c_E\}$ is a basis for $R^E$.

Now for $2\leq i \leq V$ there is a unique $v_1\to v_i$ path in $T$, this has form $p_i=\sum_{j=1}^{V-1}\mu_je_j$ where $\mu_j\in\{\pm 1, 0\}$ are coefficients to orient the edges so that $d(p_i) = v_i-v_1$. It should be immediate that $\{p_2,...,p_V\}$ is a basis for the submodule $\langle e_1,...,e_{V-1}\rangle \subset R^E$.

Thus we have $R^E \cong \langle p_2,...,p_V\rangle \oplus \langle c_V,...,c_E \rangle \cong R^{V-1}\oplus R^{E-V+1}$. Ít is immediate that $d:\langle p_2,...,p_V\rangle \rightarrow \langle v_2-v_1,...,v_V-v_1 \rangle$ is an isomorphism, and hence the first homology is $\ker d\cong \langle c_V,...,c_E\rangle \cong R^{E-V+1}$ as required.